# can someone help me with netplan removal from a 18.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: networking, 16.04, 18.04, netplan

I have 2 computers an AMD based desktop with Ubuntu desktop upgrades since 12.xx to 14.xx to 16.xx and very early on to 18.04 LTS. The network interface cannot be configured and my network connecttion often fails.  in 16.04 that was much easier.

A laptop  Samsung R540  I5 with Ubuntu desktop i tried to install 18.04 but the network didn't work, so I installed 16.04 LTS.

I have tried several times to address this situation here and questions have been removed,  an incomplete description has been posted (that I cannot find anymore) to remove netplan and go back to IP*whatever*. 
but it didn't solve my problem as some commands didn't result in the required changes or edits to config files were not described in a way that i could understand. my request didn't result in a workable solution

I have a setup on my desktop with many applications and with thesaurus and spellchecker files that have grown, and a lot of config data  which I do now  where they are and that I lack on my laptop because I don't know where they can be found and tranferring the is undocumented.

Moreover it was installed for using LVM, despite me requesting that LVM wasn't used.  I dread the consequences of the fact that I need to reinstall this - which will have to happen anyway - with 16.04 LTS  and even when I do so I will have to upgrade  not before long and move to 18.04LTS and on to 20xx LTS. 
But I need an answer to the question 
*  how i can go back to the old Network/IP configuration tools such that i can replicate that after the upgrade to 18 and later 20 LTS
lets say based on the config files of 16.04 LTS

output as requested :

derek@Avenger:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

derek@Avenger:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml cat:

```
'/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is a desktop installation, yes? If you show me your current .yaml files, I can take a look. `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Please use copy/paste, not screenshots, and edit that info into your question. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: will send req info in a few minutes

Comment: @heynnema I've appended the requested info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to return to using NetworkManager, setup your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

Your /etc/network/interfaces file should look like this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And then use the NetworkManager GUI to configure your ethernet connection.

Comment: SO i gedit a file , I can give it anyname.yaml

Comment: @DerekGiroulle As long as there's only one file, name it `01-NetworkManager.yaml`. Also see Update #1 in my answer. If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify or point me to installation instructions  of the NMgiu?

Comment: @DerekGiroulle Nothing to install. It's already there. Just pull down the upper-right menu in the top panel, and look for something like `Ethernet Disconnected` and if there's a `Wired Connection` profile, just select it. If you don't see `Wired Connection`, you'll have to add it.

Comment: there are no settings to be modified  - this is the blackbox network that I so much resent and that shows =?= status on the upper right menu 
i cannot modify anything  if I want a fixed IP address or DHCP generated address,   what my DNS servers are , no settings at all to be changed . That is why I reinstalled 16.04 on my laptop 
i may be left with days on end without a decent network connection

Comment: @DerekGiroulle I don't know what you mean by blackbox network. Apparently you've reinstalled 16.04 which doesn't have netplan, so my answer really doesn't apply. It sounds like you need to do a clean fresh install of 18.xx or newer.

Comment: I'm sorry I've had a lot of problems with my connectivity and now that I want to move to 20.04LTS  this problem becomes more pressing

  I was only talking about my 18.04 LTS installation on my desktop  I have not reinstalled  16.04LTS

Comment: what  I mean with blackbox network is  ( and Iḿ sorry I cannot post a screenshot) so I describe it with words : 
 A)in the Ubuntu main status the network icon is " =?= "  
 when click the icon   I have  a network conection  named   "wired unmanaged " 
 when I click that a drop down menu shows Ethernet0 (twice)  and wired settings 
 when I click the Ethernet0  nothing happens, 
 when I click Wired settings  I get a screen   which  says VPN  and proxy ,

Comment: nowhere I can see any settings for my network interface ( that is what I call blackbox )  I cannot selectDHCP or fixed IP address, I cannot set my DNS servers, or gateway etc

Comment: Sorry for such a brutal answer... backup your important data... then do a clean install. Much better long term results.

Comment: Yes I want to do a clean install of 20.04LTS but I will still be faced with the broken unrialable  unconfigrable blackbox networking interface  of 18.04LTS "netplan" and no workable means to change it to the configurable interface of ubuntu before 16.04LTS 
so there is no incentive to make this transition to 20.04 LTS without a reproducible way to remove netplan  and replace it with the 16.04LTS network configuration interface

Comment: @DerekGiroulle No, a fresh clean install of 18.04 or 20.04 will give you a working NetworkManager, just as you desire. Use of netplan (in a Desktop installation) is totally optional. Go for it.

Comment: I downloaded 20.04LTS  on a usbstick and started it up om my desktop  I checked how i could manage the network settings  and had it run for  72 hrs.  a few  very clear conclusions :
1-  When I looked at the network item in the main Statusbar  it didn't look like =?=  but it was a icon with three linked screens   that was promising  
2. a right click  showed  Wired Connection ‣   that allowed me to access wired settings , there were 3 bars   the wired bar showed my connection  and a settings wheel 
3. clicking that i could create new profiles,

Comment: ==>> no longer the blackbox that I was shown in my  18.04 config 
I decided there and then to   back-up, install 20.04  from scratch  allowing me to resolve my LVM issue  which according to othe articles here had to be addressed  :  no SSD and HDD in one LVM (as is was given to me.) 
Thanks for convincing me ...  I should have done this eons ago  ( when I was still young and handsome ,  now i'm only handsome)

Comment: @DerekGiroulle Glad it's all working for you now :-)

Comment: Thank you very much